# How to delete nested child using Trigger in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursive-query, triggers

I need to delete nested items in my table using triggers. I have a folder table, table have a Id and parrentID. For example

```
ID     FolderName       ParentID
--------------------------------
1          A              Null
2          B              1
3          C              2
4          D              3
```

If i delete ID 1 then it will be delete all the record 2,3,4 because 1 is a top parent. There is any way?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) says that

> [recursion] cannot be used within a CREATE TRIGGER.

However, if you declare the relationship correctly, you can tell the database [to delete the children automatically](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FolderName TEXT,
    ParentID INTEGER REFERENCES MyTable(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```